# How can use dynamic columns in linq?

Tags: c#, linq, dynamic, datatable

how can i use dynamic columns instead of this query

```
id = row.Field<int>("id") ,
rec_date = row.Field<string>("rec_date")
```

---

```
var result = from row in dt.AsEnumerable()
             group row by new
             {
                 id = row.Field<int>("id") ,
                 rec_date = row.Field<string>("rec_date")
             } into section1
             select new
             {
                 section1.Key.id,
                 section1.Key.rec_date,
                 children = from l2 in section1
                            select new
                            {
                                tax_rate = l2.Field<string>("tax_rate"),
                                tax_amount = l2.Field<string>("tax_amount")
                            }

             };

var jsonString = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(result);
```

Comment: https://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/dynamic-linq-part-1-using-the-linq-dynamic-query-library

Comment: Try this : string[][] data =   dt.AsEnumerable().Select(x => x.ItemArray.Select(y => (string)y).ToArray()).ToArray();
         }

Comment: Thanks. These are not like what i want.

Comment: Perhaps you could tell us what you want?

Comment: i using the above code. This includes static "column names" but i want change that to dynamic style @NetMage

Comment: Change __what__ to dynamic? Be specific? What is wrong with `var aField = "rec_date";` and `rec_date = row.Field<string>(aField)` ?